# Value do Input Submit com duas cores

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

Minha primeira pergunta aqui... iniciando meus estudos...

Estou com o seguinte problema:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enviar E-book">
```

Preciso que no texto do bt, "Enviar" seja de uma cor e "E-book" de outra. É possível?

Não consigo trocar por `<button>`, porque é um form importado que já vem com essa tag input.

Comment: primeiro qual a finalidade disso? ou seja, para que?

Comment: finalidade estética, é o que a pessoa quer

Comment: Se a resposta abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 5):

Veja a documentação [`<button>`: The Button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) :

> Conteúdo permitido: Permitido [conteúdo fraseado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) mas não [conteúdo interativo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#interactive_content).

Então apenas coloque um conteúdo válido dentro do botão e aplique um estilo.

```css
.txt1 {
  color: red;
}

.txt2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">
  <span class="txt1">Enviar</span>
  <span class="txt2">E-book</span>
</button>
```

Então no seu caso como o botão do servidor vem como `<input>` e esse elemento não suporta conteúdo aninhado. Pegue a referência do input e substitua por um `<button>` usando a propriedade [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) que descreve o código HTML do elemento incluindo seus descendentes.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.outerHTML = `
   <button class="button">
      <span class="txt1">Enviar</span>
      <span class="txt2">E-book</span>
   </button>`;
```

```css
.txt1 {
  color: red;
}

.txt2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btn">
```

Comment: No relato dele, ele não consegue trocar o tipo do elemento de **input** para **button**, logo, não daria para aplicar sua resposta Augusto.

Comment: @LeAndrade, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Eu estava com medo da pergunta ser fechada antes de conseguir responder e mandei metade

Comment: Entendi Augusto : )

Comment: +1 pelo ideia de usar `outerHTML`. Não sabia dessa...